# PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA upon booting when CSM is disabled

Tags: windows-10, bsod, uefi, efi

I have Win10 installed on a GPT drive (nvme) as the 3rd partition (EFI, HFS, NTFS - that one has Win10). It boots through UEFI, thus I don't understand why if I disable CSM in BIOS (which I want to, but that's outside of this question's scope), windows fails to boot with PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA error. That happens after few "spins" of Windows logo during booting.

I don't know how to debug it further to understand what exactly is failing during the boot. Is there any way to, for example, boot the OS in debug mode (without windows logo covering whats happening under the hood) as well as logging the EFI output to a text file?

Comment: This usually means invalid system memory has been referenced.  It would appear to be some software you have installed causing this. It can be caused by a root kit virus.

Comment: Windows updates is the biggest root kit windows has. Are you aware of any convenient way to debug this to see which process or driver caused that?

Comment: You can try the vendor's driver update app, but errant software won't be repaired by driver updates. Drivers usually produce a different error (IRQ NE type of error)